# Is it possible to obtain the web server's ip address in one-time authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, ip-address

I have two application hosted in different web server.
web server1 hosting the main application (main app) and web server2 hosting the sub application (sub app).
From main app's menu, I put a link to sub app. When it is clicked, it will submit via POST method.

Is it possible to obtain the web server1's IP address?
The reason behind is, would like to filter the request from web server1.

I am using C# MVC4

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you realize that in this scenario the request to server2 will be submitted from the user's IP address, not from the server1's address?

Answer (score 0):

The post is actually happening on the client browser so its not going to give you the IP address of the server that posted the information.

That being said, have you looked at the [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property? This should give you some information on who referred the client to the requested URL.

Now it is worth noting that this property is only available if the client is referred to your page from another page. With this in mind remeber that this property *may* be `null`.

Hope this helps